# PHP Add all Values in Array Excluding Last

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

`Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 3 )`

I'd like to get the sum of the values excluding the last value.

So in this example I'm looking to find the answer to 1 + 1.

The array could be varying lengths.

Comment: Look at the `count()` function to check how many elements in the array, go from there.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are supposed to show a bit of effort yourself here, not just drop off your requirements. This should contain _at least_ something along the lines of “I tried this, [code example], but instead of the desired result, I got this, [actual problem description]”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like this

```
$myArray= [1,1,3];
array_pop($myArray); // Remove the last element from array
echo array_sum($myArray); // Sum the values of the array
```

Comment: Thanks for this I marked as the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<?php $array = array(1, 1, 3);
$sliced = array_slice($array, 0, -1); ?>
```

This will return you 1 & 1 it won't give you 3

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php $value = array(1,1,3);
$removed = array_pop($value);
echo array_sum($value);
?>
```

Comment: just a few notes.. 1) it's better to explain your answers so people can learn from them. 2) when it's a PHP only script, you don't need the closing `?>` tag. 3) code should have new lines, unless it's a one-liner, drop everything under the opening php tag

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do using closure

```
$array = [1,1,3];
echo array_sum(array_filter($array, function($key) use ($array) {
  return count($array) - 1 !== $key;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
```

Answer (score -1):

try this its very simple & fastest way

```
// initialize array by 'short syntax'
$a = [
    1,1,3
];

//remove last element of array no matter length
// This function will reset() the array pointer of the input array after use.
array_pop($a);
// then you can sum of rest array values by array_sum
echo array_sum($a);
```

Comment: At the very least there should be a warning that this method alters the array.